# How to copy the lag event to all the subsequent duplicate rows?

Tags: google-bigquery

How can I copy the lag event to all the succeeding rows, till a matching column value comes up?

Ex. If I a given a table like this:

```
id    activity  eid   
101   play      A1    
101   eat       null  
101   eat       null  
102   play      A3    
102   eat       null  
102   eat       null  
102   eat       null  
102   eat       null
```

Then the desired output should be:

```
id    activity  eid   lag_event
101   play      A1     A1
101   eat       null   A1
101   eat       null   A1
102   play      A3     A3
102   eat       null   A3
102   eat       null   A3
102   eat       null   A3
102   eat       null   A3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL (and assumes you have some extra column that defines the order of events - in below example I am using column named `ts` with data type of TIMESTAMP)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  LAST_VALUE(eid IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) AS lag_event
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example -

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-08-28 07:01:16.888891 UTC' ts, 101 id, 'play' activity, 'A1' eid UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:02:16.888891 UTC', 101, 'eat', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:03:16.888891 UTC', 101, 'eat', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:04:16.888891 UTC', 102, 'play', 'A3' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:05:16.888891 UTC', 102, 'eat', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:06:16.888891 UTC', 102, 'eat', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:07:16.888891 UTC', 102, 'eat', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT '2020-08-28 07:08:16.888891 UTC', 102, 'eat', NULL 
)
SELECT *, 
  LAST_VALUE(eid IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ts) AS lag_event
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```
Row ts                              id          activity    eid     lag_event    
1   2020-08-28 07:01:16.888891 UTC  101         play        A1      A1   
2   2020-08-28 07:02:16.888891 UTC  101         eat         null    A1   
3   2020-08-28 07:03:16.888891 UTC  101         eat         null    A1   
4   2020-08-28 07:04:16.888891 UTC  102         play        A3      A3   
5   2020-08-28 07:05:16.888891 UTC  102         eat         null    A3   
6   2020-08-28 07:06:16.888891 UTC  102         eat         null    A3   
7   2020-08-28 07:07:16.888891 UTC  102         eat         null    A3   
8   2020-08-28 07:08:16.888891 UTC  102         eat         null    A3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use forward fill on eid column refer bigQuery [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/FILL-Function_57344752)

```
fill(eid,-1,0)
```

Comment: I actually wanted a Bigquery.
thanks for your help.

Comment: what does it mean by the big query? mention your problem properly.

Comment: I want a standard bigquery syntax for the above problem.
thanks

Comment: anyway this is forward fill 
use fill(eid,-1,0)